# Returning non-const attribute reference from const function

Tags: c++, reference

Is there something wrong with this code?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A( std::vector<int>& ref ) : data(ref) {}

    std::vector<int>& getData() const { return data; }

private:
    std::vector<int>& data;
};

void modifyA( const A& a )
{
    a.getData().push_back(3);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> foo;
    A a(foo);
    modifyA(a);
    std::cout << foo.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo.front() << std::endl;
}
```

It looks good to me, but I'm experiencing undefined behaviour under Android when deploying a much more complex code with similar approach. At some point, a member (a `shared_ptr`) of the class gets corrupted when the previous member of the class (a `std::vector`) is modified through such a getter (the `shared_ptr` becomes `NULL`, while it was not modified at all). I also saw the program above return unexpected values on http://cpp.sh at some point but not consistently. In the end, I could not isolate the problem in a MVCE...

I'm just wondering if returning a non-const reference to a non-const member from a const getter could possibly be a problem.

Comment: What'Who owns `A.data?` What's to stop it from dangling?

Comment: @Alexander: In the original code,  ̀A.data` is owned by the class that creates and destroys `A` instance in one of its member functions. So `A.data` is guaranteed to remain alive during `A` lifetime (as it does in the example posted here). I agree this could have been a problem if the vector was destroyed before A, but I don't think that's the cause of the undefined behaviour here.

Comment: I'm very suspicious of that, and I would investigate that further, if I were you.

Comment: To be honest given example is not related to those "undefined behaviour" and "member of the class gets corrupted" problems. Basically it is the same as storing (and returning) const pointer to non-const data which is [a common practice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get).

Comment: in any case, returning a non const ref from a const member function is a terrible idea.

Comment: It is fine. Just like holding a pointer to something someone else owns.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm wondering a bit why `mutual` for `data` isn't required. Because it's an injected non `const` reference?

Comment: @user0042 Because the member is a non-const reference to a different object. Pretty much the same as having a const pointer to non-const.

Comment: @user0042 Do you mean `mutable`?

Comment: @VTT Of course. It seems to start I'm getting rusty.

Comment: @user0042 actually `mutable` specifier is not allowed on reference types at all.

Comment: @VTT As you say that, it seems not to be reasonable, yes.

Comment: @VTT: I was about to ask if adding `mutable` could help....but you answered that...

Answer (score 4):

This code can easily lead to undefined behavior. Consider this example, based on what you said in comments:

```
struct B {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  A a;
  B() : vec{}, a{vec} {}
};

int main() {
  const B b;

  auto& vec = b.a.getData();

  vec.push_back(0);
}
```

I have a const object, and by extension all its members are const. But here I am getting a non-const reference to one of these const objects. No warning, no explicit ugly cast. Just silent nasal demons.

Even if the ownership is never a problem, this is just terribly error prone.

Comment: Maybe this is not the best reference sharing pattern but there are no nasal demons of any kind within the given example. Just because `b` is declared as const-qualified does not mean that it is prohibited to hold a non-const-qualified references to its fields and to modify them.

Comment: @VTT - Modifying an object originally declared const is UB, even if the qualifier appears on a super-object originally. Classic nasal demons. If you postulate it's not, please support it with a normative reference.

Comment: @StoryTeller: In what situation would this end up with UB. Could the OS/compiler decide to store the const object in a kind of "read-only" memory that could prevent it from being correctly modified through a non-const reference retrieved as illustrated?

Comment: @jpo38 - That's one way exactly. Other ways involve how compiler vendors optimize when they have const references on their hands. [They have explicit license to go crazy](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.cv#4).

Comment: @StoryTeller The standard supplies the `mutable` workaround anyway. But in OP's example even this potential UB with const-qualification object change does not appear as original object is not const-qualified.

Comment: @VTT - I specifically addressed the OP's comment about a common container object and provided an illustration about that itself being problematic. What exactly are you on about? You wanna comment on the OP's example, comment on their post. Your comment when applied to mine is purely factually incorrect.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That's intesting because my code crashes with g++ on Android but works perfecly fine with msvc under Windows

Comment: @jpo38 - The very nature of UB. Different vendors can do vastly different things. GCC in particular is known for some aggressive optimizations.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That's even more interesting that, when I debug my code (using QtCreator), in "Debug" mode (that has the UB) on Android, I see that the member getting corrupted at some point is marked "optimized away"....which looked strange to me as I compiled in Debug...but maybe it was badly optimized away and this messed things up at some point.

Comment: @jpo38 - As an attempt at a quick fix, you may try to mark the vector object as `mutable` in the containing common object (`B` in my example). That may alleviate the problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller: This will not apply to my original code. In my case, the `vector` is actually a non-const reference passed to the function that, within its scope, creates `A` instance storing a ref to the vector and passing this same `A` instance as const ref to another function that will end up modifying the vector accessed through the const getter....so the only thing I could make `mutable` would be the const ref to the vector (member of `A`), not the vector itself....

Comment: @StoryTeller: Maybe I'll try not to pass A instance as const ref anymore and make the getter non-const and see if this, by chance, fixes the issue.

Comment: @StoryTeller I basically agree with you. IMHO, _the_ difference is: in your sample you made a member `vector<int> a;` but in the question it was a reference `vector<int> &a;`. In the first case, I had never doubt that a `const` method returning a non-const reference _is bad_. In the latter case, I cannot tell why this is a problem. (In my stomache feeling, a reference is something like "borrowed". So, why restricting something without "real ownership" is necessary? But I would like to learn.) I would be really happy if you could elaborate this.

Comment: @Scheff - Well, my whole exposé was about pointing out that the issue is larger than mere ownership. That this combo of a const member returning a non-const reference is likely to be error prone. I mean, this `B` I cooked up is fairly simple. But it broke it less than 20 lines. Imagine UB in a far more complex system, like the OP's by their own admission.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sounds for me like: "Don't ask why - just don't do it. It's a _Don't do it._" I'm not quite satisfied but I will keep this in mind (seriously). (I'm just digging in mind where in our productive software could this be done wrong. Probably, only rare cases but, now, I'm concerned a little bit...)

Comment: @Scheff - I tried to illustrate where it may break. Imagine all of this happens across translation units. Where the compiler is unaware of any connection between the vector and the `A`. And just like GCC is notorious for, it starts doing interesting things based off of those assumptions. Just because you can't *see* the point of breakage, doesn't mean it's safe. I'm not trying to preach dogma here, I have an example for a reason.